# Web app for splitting PDF pages

Tags: webapp-rec, pdf

Are there any Web apps that either automatically or manually can split scanned PDFs into multiple pages?

At school, I receive many scanned PDFs that have two physical pages per PDF page, which makes them slightly more cumbersome to work with since it requires me tok manually pan around to see the next page.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of online services to achieve what you want. Some of them are:

- [FoxyUtils Split PDF](http://foxyutils.com/splitpdf/)
- [Split PDF Online](http://www.splitpdfonline.com/)
- [I Love PDF](http://www.ilovepdf.com/split_pdf)

Comment: Actually it appears that none of those apps solve the OP question.  They extract PDF page ranges rather than splitting the physical scanned images.